Various groupings of 8th, 16th, 32nd, etc. notes with beams
In the book Music Theory for Dummies it was mentioned:


These three groups of sixteenth (semiquaver) notes, written in three different ways,
all sound alike when played.

However, when I look at some sheet music, I see that different ways of beaming have been used for adjacent flagged notes. For example, some of them may beam eight quavers in one group, or use two groups of four quavers, and so on.
Considering that different ways of beaming don't affect how the notes are played, I wonder what determines how the adjacent notes are grouped by beaming. I think one thing that affects different beaming is the time signature, which specifies the number of beats in a bar. In addition, the legibility of the sheet of music might also affect it. Am I right, and are there other things that affect it?

Beaming is a concept of engraving which is not strictly necessary. The purpose of Beaming is to make scores easier to read. The exact mode of beaming will depend on what it is supposed to achieve. There is some sort of standard mode of beaming, which is what most notation software will do by default. Here a beamed group will usually make up one beat (e.g. a quarter in 4/4, 3 8th in 6/8, ...), with a lot of exceptions (e.g. in 4/4 8th notes are beamed as groups of 4, not 2, and in 3/4 8th notes are beamed over the whole measure).
But there are other things that can be conveyed by beaming. Especially in older engravings of vocal music it is common practice to use beams for melismas, i.e. when multiple notes fall on the same syllable. In solo literature (especially piano literature) beams are heavily used to designate phrases, which can even lead to beams over bar lines and such stuff. Also in piano music beaming in combination with stem direction is commonly used to split notes beween the two hands.
In this example:

you can see beaming aligned to beats for instruments with exceptions of 8th note beaming, but use for melismas for the choir. Note that beaming of long melimas will also be divided into separate groups.
On the other hand if you take e.g. Chopin you’ll find beams like this

or

In these cases the beaming is used to clearly notate a specific phrasing.
The choice of beams often follows some basic rules, but a occasionally an editor/composer will need to make good choices for beaming, which requires skill, experience and a good sense of what looks good.

Thank you for including an example where the beam straddles a bar line.  It would be great to add where the examples come from (name of the pieces).

@GratefulDisciple I think the first piece is number 3 from the Op. 10 Etudes and the second the Rondo Op. 1, both Chopin.

@11684 Correct. The first one is from BWV 190.

Huh, somehow I completely overlooked the first example when writing my previous comment

As a longtime singer, my experience is that vocal music should be beamed without regards to the words being sung (in particular, different syllables should not be a reason to unbeam notes that would normally be beamed), because standard beaming makes the music easier to read—the formatting of the text gives enough information about which syllables go with which notes. (This is in response to the accurate comment that sometimes people do/used to unbeam notes in vocal music based on the words.)

Beaming serves to communicate information, whether that is showing rhythmic grouping, or phrasing, or something else (particularly in piano music), and as a result, makes music easier to read. While you can read music without it, dismissing it as "not strictly necessary" is a bit of a stretch.

@GregMartin As a longtime singer I would say it heavily depends on the type of music. Music with high rhythmic complexity profits from beaming with default rules. For conventional music that employs a lots of melismas it can be quite hard to quickly see what text goes where with just slurs. This is less relevant for modern computer engravings, because most software avoids spacing problems by using very wide horizontal spacing, making it very easy to see what text goes where. But with traditionally engraved scores the text is often quite densely packed, so this dated convention can really help.

@benwiggy Try to read the whole answer and you will see that I elaborated on exactly that instead of being triggered by a single sentence out of context, especially when clearly not understanding what it says. You seem to read “beaming is a concept that is not strictly necessary (but it serves to make the score easier to read or convey phrasing)”. In your mind I probably now said: “Beaming serves no purpose”. But I did not say this. Rather: Somethings in notation are necessary. Without heads and flags we cannot simply omit. Beams we could omit.

@benwiggy ... And the reason for that sentence is to show that other than these things beams are not something that is inherently necessary for the music, which means it leaves choice to composer and editor. I am not “dismissing” anything.

@Lazy I agree that my sensibility is very much shaped be modern engraving

It's quite a big subject, but some points are as follows.
In 3/4 time, semiquavers can be used for each beat. Thus three groups of four.
In 6/8 time, there'll be two beams, each containing six semis.
In 12/8, with four stresses, there will be four groups of three semis.
In 4/4, each crotchet value will have four semis, so in a full bar of semis, there will be four beams of four each. The thing to watch here is that if those semis are mixed with other values, it's best to write the bar out so that semis on the 1st half and those on the 2nd don't share the same beam. It makes it so much easier to read, knowing where the centre of the bar, therefore beat three actually is.
So, for clarity, the idea is to beam only each beat, when that's played as semis.
This is in essence a basic premise.
